# Python - How to get the attribute behind @property

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, properties

How can I get the attribute behind a property in Python? I have the following scenario:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._email = None

    @property
    def email(self):
       return self._email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, value):
         self._email = value
```

What I wan to achieve is to get the _email attribute which is behind email property using reflection.
Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general way to do this, since a property doesn't have to simply be a proxy for a private attribute. You could have any of the following:

```
@property
def foo(self):
    return 4

@property
def bar(self):
    return self._bar**2

@property
def baz(self):
    sys.exit(1)

@property
def spam(self):
    if self._spam is None:
        self._spam = self._lazily_compute_spam()
    return self._spam
```

If you wanted to try it anyway, you could try to get the source code of the property method with the `inspect` module and parse it, or decompile the bytecode, but both are terribly fragile ideas.

Comment: Shame on me, I totally missed the point of properties. I was to focused on trying to have SQLAlchemy classical mapping work with properties.